# Twilio C# API Callback Unsupported Media type

Tags: c#, twilio

I have a callback url that is supposed to trigger this function:

```
[HttpPost("MDOrigin")]
public void MDOrigin([FromBody] MessageResource Input)
{
    var flat = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Input);
    WMO whatsappMO = new WMO
    {
        Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
        Content = flat,
        CreatedOn = DateTime.Now,
    };
    WMOData.Save(whatsappMO);
}
```

However, when a message is sent, I get these errors in the Twilio console:

```
{
    "type": "https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.13",
    "title": "Unsupported Media Type",
    "status": 415,
    "traceId": "|d39885-450438eba9e4e0f3."
}
```

What format does Twilio send out its messages in?
I have tried application/json and it works.

I am unsure of the input I am even supposed to be receiving. There doesnt seem to be much in the docs about this.

Answer (score 1):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

Twilio webhooks are sent in the format `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. The webhooks also expect a response, either with an empty body or in the format `application/xml` or `text/xml`.

I don't know C# or the framework you are using there, but it doesn't appear that you are sending a response. If you can set your endpoint to respond with a `text/xml` response of:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response/>
```

then you should stop seeing the unsupported media type errors.

Comment: Hi @philnash, thanks for the reply. I realized the proper format after that. I am using .net core 3.1 at the moment. I realized that the docs for c# showed incorrect return fields as well when I checked the body of the request coming in.